# TransactionScope throws exception

Tags: c#, linq, transactionscope

Im sure this is so basic question but i can't found any solution on google neither here.

when im trying to use that code block it throws an exception that
'System.Activities.Statements.TransactionScope': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

`using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
{
}`

Simply, i want to use TransactionScope in Linq code.

Thanks,
Regards

Comment: Perhaps, you'd better check your project references, ensure it's the right type (in System.Transactions)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are likely using the wrong TransactionScope.

The one you're looking for is `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`, which resides in the System.Transactions.dll assembly. Make sure it's referenced (it's not by default), and that you are "`using System.Transactions`".

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what `System.Activities.Statements.TransactionScope` is but you want [`System.Transactions.TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx). You'll also need a reference to `System.Transactions.dll`.

From the documentation:

```
public sealed class TransactionScope : IDisposable
```

Note that `System.Activities.Statements.TransactionScope` lives in `System.Activities.Statements` which is described as

> The `System.Activities.Statements` namespace contains activities that can be used to create workflows. This namespace contains activities that are used for flow control, interacting with collections and variables, exceptions, compensation, transactions, and interacting with legacy workflows.

which is clearly not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong `TransactionScope` class. The right one is in the `System.Transactions` namespace. Your error indicates that you are using another class from `System.Activities.Statements`.